# How to include the startdate when create the date->diff in php

Tags: php, date, datediff

How to include the startdate as well. When you count days it omits the first day, but i want to include the first day as well.

```
$d1 = '2018-02-01 00:00:00';
$d2 = '2018-02-05 00:00:00';

function timeDifference($dT1, $dT2){
    $d1 = new DateTime($dT1);
    $d2 = new DateTime($dT2);
    $d = $d1->diff($d2);
    $total = $d->days;
    $month = $d->m.' months';
    $days = $d->d.' days';
    if ($total > 30) {
        $returnDate = $month.' '.$days;
    }
    else {
        $returnDate = $days;
    }
    return $returnDate;
}

echo timeDifference($d1, $d2); // 4 (i want 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the difference between the 01. and 05. is four days, it's not ignoring anything. Why don't you do it like that?

€dit: Please note that this can still go wrong for a date difference which will exceed a month  (e.g. 30 days +1 = 31, but the month only has 30 days...)

```
<?PHP
$d1 = '2018-02-01 00:00:00';
$d2 = '2018-02-05 00:00:00';

function timeDifference($dT1, $dT2){
    $d1 = new DateTime($dT1);
    $d2 = new DateTime($dT2);
    $d = $d1->diff($d2);
    $total = $d->days;
    $month = $d->m.' months';
    $dayDifference = $d->d;
    if($dayDifference !== 0)
    {
        $dayDifference++;
    }
    $days = $dayDifference.' days';

    if ($total > 30) {
        $returnDate = $month.' '.$days;
    }
    else {
        $returnDate = $days;
    }
    return $returnDate;
}

echo timeDifference($d1, $d2);
?>
```

## 2:

```
<?PHP
$d1 = '2018-02-01 00:00:00';
$d2 = '2018-02-05 00:00:00';

function timeDifference($dT1, $dT2){
    $d1 = new DateTime($dT1);
    $d1->sub(new DateInterval("P1D"));
    $d2 = new DateTime($dT2);
    $d = $d1->diff($d2);
    $total = $d->days;
    $month = $d->m.' months';
    $days = $d->d.' days';
    if ($total > 30) {
        $returnDate = $month.' '.$days;
    }
    else {
        $returnDate = $days;
    }
    return $returnDate;
}

echo timeDifference($d1, $d2);
?>
```

Comment: when the user selects '01 Jan' and '05 Jan', i want to return 5 days. The calculation is for 5 days and not 4 days.

Comment: Then it might be the best to pick the start date, parse it, and substract one day. I'll append the second version in a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The function works as expected. Between date `2018-02-01 00:00:00` and date  `2018-02-05 00:00:00` there are effectively 4 days (01, 02, 03, 04). 
The fifth is not counted because the date `2018-02-05 00:00:00` is considered as the upper limit.
If you wish your function returns 5 instead of 4, make the increment inside it or make the right hand side input date `2018-02-06 00:00:00`.